# Request post return an empty object in NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, fetch

I don't know why but i try to send an object in my back. I can find good information in my network's payload but my req.body return everytime an empty object

[my probleme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry6SF.png)

Comment: Your server isn't sending anything back.

Comment: `app.post` you have doesn't send anything back. it only logs the request received into the console of the process running it. if you're talking about `console.log(res)` you have in your front-end: it won't have any response in it unless your back-end sends something. in your back-end try adding `res.status(200).json({"my": "response"})`

Comment: Add code as text

Comment: I tested with `res.status(200).json({"my": req.body})` but my response is empty again `{my: {…}}`

Comment: what is `console.log(req)` showing of the server side?

Answer (score 0):

add `app.use(express.json());`

`express.json()` is a middleware that allows express to recognise the json data in request object.
Also your controller is not sending any response back, for that use:

```js
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({"data" : req.body});
}
```